# right/left align subtitle position in plot

Tags: r, plot, subtitle

How can I change the position of the subtitle in r "base" plot. Is there a special argument? I want to dynamically have the subtitle left or right aligned.

#### data

```
plot(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$qsec,xlab="",sub="I WANT TO\nBE RIGHT\nALIGNED")
```

#### plot data with desired output in red

[image]

#### EDIT

```
plottR <- function(...) {
    plot(...)
}

plottR(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$qsec, ylab="Y Must Center", xlab="X Must Center", main="Must center", sub="Must right-align",adj=1)
```

Can I input something to plottR so it only aligns the subtitle?

#### EDIT2

I just found out. I can evaluate the `title()` inside plot.

```
plottR(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$qsec, ylab="Y Must Center", xlab="X Must Center", main = "Must Center", title(sub ="Hey Only\nim right\ncool huh?",adj=1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the `par` setting `adj`. From the help page:

*A value of 0 produces left-justified text, 0.5 (the default) centered text and 1 right-justified text. (Any value in [0, 1] is allowed, and on most devices values outside that interval will also work.)*

The drawback is that it influences the way text is justified for `text`, `mtext`, and `title`. Hence we have to break up the code in  pieces if we want to leave e.g. the title and the Y-axis title untouched.

You could use the following code:

```
# store the current value of adj
adj.old <- par()$adj    # default is 0.5

# plot with the current value of adj
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$qsec, xlab="")

# set adj to right-aligned and plot the subtitle
par(adj = 1)
title(sub = "I WANT TO\nBE RIGHT\nALIGNED")

# reset adj to previous value
par(adj = adj.old)
```

This generates the following graph:

[image]

Comment: thank you. I found adj parameter. Its not mentioned in my question but the adj would also shift the main title. Is there a way to only shift the subtitle?

Comment: @AndreElrico this is essentially what I did in the code above. I generate a graph with `plot` without the subtitle but with the Y axis title **(you could add a main title here as well)** under conditions where `adj` has its default value (0.5). Then, I change `adj = 1` and I add the subtitle with the `title` function. Lastly I reset `adj`.

Comment: it works. Thats probably the best solution there is. Sadly im working with a function that calls plot and i am working in the `...` argument. So i cant procedurally code in there. But thats a good workaround :-)

Comment: @AndreElrico It is just a suggestion: you could take the code above, graph included, and post a new question asking for an alternative that fits your needs. If you let me inform me about the new question I will cenrtainly consider voting it up. Good Luck!

Comment: hey i just updated the question to match my situation more precisely. If you have any ideas, suggestions let me know :-)

Comment: @AndreElrico I really think you should post a **new** question, asking for an alternative way. This question is already "old" now, and will attract less attention.